# Are UIGestureRecognizer's coming to an the iPhone not just the iPad

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I want to use the `UIGestureRecognizer` class inside the iPhone (not the iPad), is Apple going to come out with that some time soon?

Comment: None of us really know the future of the SDK, so this isn't a question we can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the SDK, I don't see *how* it wouldn't be available. I'd suspect yes. Everything indicates it's a SDK class that is documented and available.

Comment: I believe 3.2 isn't going to be released for iPhone. 3.2 will be iPad only. iPhone OS 3.1.x and 3.2 will converge at the 4.0 mark. At that point, you can probably expect `UIGestureRecognizer`s to be available on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Who knows? Really, you're asking about something nobody knows for sure.

Besides I'd assume these new APIs will be introduced on the iPhone and iPod touch via another OS update like 4.0.

Comment: That was exactly what I had expected... To bad I have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  :)  Hindsight is 20/20.  Just putting a Yes here for anyone else that comes across this question later.